# Laravel excel export using laravel excel killing server

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am trying to export an excel file, or a simple csv using laravel excel library but for some reason anything I do with the laravel excel library completly kills the server. Here is me calling the endpoint from postman

[image: Requesting export endpoint]

and this is what my code looks like in the controller

```html
public function exportPurchases(Request $request)
    {
        $query = QueryBuilder::for(Purchase::class)
            ->with(['customer', 'productCategory'])
            ->allowedFilters(
                [
                    AllowedFilter::partial('product_no')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('model_no')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('serial_no')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('productCategory.name')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::scope('date_of_purchase_lte')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::scope('date_of_purchase_gte')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('customer.first_name')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('customer.surname')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('customer.mobile')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('customer.email')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('customer.town')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('customer.region')->ignore(['']),
                    AllowedFilter::partial('dealer.name')->ignore(['']),
                ]);
        Excel::store(new PurchaseExport($query), 'purchases.csv', 'public');
        return [];
    }
```

It does not matter if I do Excel::store or Excel::download, the result is the same, I have gb extension enabled, infact on another project running on the very same php server I am able to generate and download excel files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake, in the purchase exports on the headings function I had a self referencing function as I had a private array property called headings I was supposed to return there instead of calling it as a function.

```html
public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->headings();
    }
```

correct was

```html
public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->headings;
    }
```